# Printing object attributes based on user input in Python 3x

Tags: python

First of all I'd like to say im a Python beginner (or programming beginner for that matter) and I'm trying to figure out how to print attributes from a object based on user input.

This is the code I have so far:

```
class Customer:
    "De klasse customer"

    def __init__(self, naam, adres, woonplaats, email):   
        self.naam = naam
        self.adres = adres
        self.woonplaats = woonplaats
        self.email = email

input1 = input ("Enter the object name")
print(input1.naam) ## ** << This is what i like to know**

a = Customer('Name1', 'address', 'Utrecht', 'Email1@hotmail.com')
b = Customer('Name2', 'Bonestaak', 'Maarssen', 'Bijjaapishetaltijdraakhotmail.com')
```

So I basically want this: `print(a.naam)` to work, but the 'a' must be entered by a user.

Did some searching but no success so far.

Comment: This class docstring does not provide any new information; please don't bother to add one unless it actually has a use :)

Comment: Anyway, that is wrong thinking about the problem; your customer already has a name (the `naam` attribute), and **variable** names are supposed to be under your control. Think about it: if you leave it up to the user to name your variable, then how do you expect to know what name to use, so you can check what is in the variable and use it? You are writing the code before the user gives you a name...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `locals` function:

```
>>> a = {1:'abc'}
>>> obj = raw_input('Obj?> ')
Obj?> a
>>> print locals()[obj][1]
abc
>>>
```

This is however an **highly** insecure construct (there are other things in locals!)

---

A cleaner way would be to:

```
customers = {
    'a' : Customer('Name1', 'address', 'Utrecht', 'Email1@hotmail.com')
    'b' : Customer('Name2', 'Bonestaak', 'Maarssen', 'Bijjaapishetaltijdraakhotmail.com')
}

customer = raw_input('Customer? > ')
print customers[customer].naam
```

You'll need to handle `KeyError` properly though!